# perform Post method on current page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this form where I'm sending a mail (via **Post** method) :

```
<form method="POST" action="sendmail.php">
  <input type="text" name="sender_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
  <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">
</form>
```

and here's my `sendmail.php` :

```
<?php
  if($_POST['send'] == 'SEND'){    
    $to      = 'queries@mydomain.com';
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['sender_nam‌​e​']." <".$_POST['sender_em‌​ail‌​'].">\r\n"; $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['sender_ema‌​il‌​']."\r\n"; 
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
?>
```

As you can see that in above code I'm sending a mail which is working fine, but the above action is executing by leaving current page

e.g before posting my url is `mydomain.com` after posting it becomes `mydomain.com/sendmail.php`.

So how can i execute above function without leaving current page?

Comment: Please use ajax request if you don't want to reload the page .

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about Ajax and jQuery? Read more, [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Your ajax call can look like this.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "yourApplication/methodWhichSendsEmail",
      type: "post",
      data:JSON.stringify({
           to : $to,
           subject: $subject,
           message: $message,
           headers: $headers
})

}).done(function() {
  //Whatever you want to do once the request is succeed. As you don't want to reload. i.e.
  alert("Email Sent");
});
```

Comment: where do i have to make this call in my index.html ? @superCoder

Comment: Include jQuery in your page, and the above JavaScript code in a <script> tag. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Either by AJAX or you can do the following:

1. You specify `action=""` in the `<form>`
2. You include the code from `sendmail.php` to `index.php` (or whatever your homepage is)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your form action empty.

Then in PHP code you need to check if form is posted or not. SO need to check it first by php function isset then you can do whatever you want, This will only send email if a form is posted

```
  if(isset ($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] == 'SEND'){    
    $to      = 'queries@mydomain.com';
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['sender_nam‌​e​']." <".$_POST['sender_em‌​ail‌​'].">\r\n"; $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['sender_ema‌​il‌​']."\r\n"; 
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
```