# send mail (mail to php Post method) using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i'm sending mail from my html page by executing a Php function,  my index.html :

```
  <form method="POST" action="sendmail.php" >
 <input type="text" name="sender_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
 <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
 <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
 <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">

    </form>
```

my sendmail.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['send'] == 'SEND'){

$to      = 'queries@mydomain.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$headers = "From: ".$_POST['sender_nam‌​e​']." <".$_POST['sender_em‌​ail‌​'].">\r\n"; $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['sender_ema‌​il‌​']."\r\n"; 
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

the above is working fine  but its also leaving current page i wanna execute the above method on current page and for that according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792298/perform-post-method-on-current-page) & this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

i have to use **Ajax** and **jQuery**? and i know nothing about them so far i have this :

```
////in my index.html
<button type="button">send mail</button>
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmail.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data)
                    $("l").text(data);

                }
            });
   });
});
</script>
```

i know above is not correct & its not working (currently its showing sendmail.php's text in a popup) how can i make it work so that i can execute sendmail.php ???

UPDATE:

**index.html**

```
    <form method="POST" id="myForm" action="sendmail.php">
  <input type="text" name="sender_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
  <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">
</form>



</div>
<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myForm").on('submit', function(){
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmail.php',
                data: formData,
                success: function(response.success) {
                    alert(response.success)
                    $("l").text(response.success);

                }
            });
   });
</script>
    `
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below should work for you using `.on('submit'` and `.serialize()`

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm" action="sendmail.php">
  <input type="text" name="sender_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
  <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sendmail.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            success: function(response) { 
                alert(response.success); 
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(xhr); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $to      = 'queries@mydomain.com';
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['sender_nam‌​e​']." <".$_POST['sender_em‌​ail‌​'].">\r\n"; $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['sender_ema‌​il‌​']."\r\n"; 
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) echo json_encode(['success'=>true]); 
    else echo json_encode(['success'=>false]);
    exit;
 }
?>
```

Comment: is this is how i'm supposed to do it ? please check updated question

Comment: @remyboys Yeah, this should work for your use. Are you having some issue with it or getting an error?

Comment: @remyboys make sure you add the `function(event){event.preventDefault();` bit as shown above, without that, it wont work. I forgot it when I first added my answer but edited it after

Comment: where to add it ? `function(event){event.preventDefault();` @DelightedD0D

Comment: @remyboys add it just like it's shown in the `js` section above and you should be good

Comment: dont know what i' doing wrong but its not working ,  its redirecting my sendmail.php page but now mail is not delivering anymore

Comment: @remyboys can you post an update with your code with the `preventDefault` bit added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128997/discussion-between-remy-boys-and-delightedd0d).

Comment: just sent you over chat , please take a look

Answer (score 4):

So give and id for your form tag like the following code.

```
 <form method="POST" action="sendmail.php" id="sendForm">
 <input type="text" name="sender_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
 <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
 <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
 <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required="">  
 </textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND" id="submitButton">    
 </form>
```

Then update your script like the following code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submitButton").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
        var datas = $('#sendForm').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmail.php',
                data: datas,

                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data)
                    $("l").text(data);

                }
            });
   });
});
```

Check this [url](https://webdesignerhut.com/pass-data-with-ajax-to-a-php-file/) for how to submit form data using ajax

Comment: Dont forget to call `event.preventDefault();` or the html form will be submitted via the normal process and the page will refresh before the ajax gets called ;)

Comment: Sure..Thank you for notifying me

Answer (score 3):

```
<form id="my_form" method="POST" action="sendmail.php" >
 <input type="text" name="sender_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
 <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
 <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
 <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
  <input id="my_button" type="button" name="send" value="SEND">
</form>
```

jQuery Code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#my_button").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmail.php',
                data : $('#my_form').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
   });
```

Php code

```
<?php

$searcharray = array();
parse_str($_POST['data'], $searcharray);
if($searcharray['send'] == 'SEND'){

$to      = 'queries@mydomain.com';
$subject = $searcharray['subject']; 
$message = $searcharray['message']; 
$headers = "From: ".$searcharray['sender_nam‌​e​']." <".$searcharray['sender_em‌​ail‌​'].">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$searcharray['sender_ema‌​il‌​']."\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi give your form an `id` and use `JS` `preventDefault()`

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm" action="sendmail.php">
  <input type="text" name="sender_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
  <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="sendMail" name="send" value="SEND">
</form>
```

sendmail.php

```
<?php
    if($_POST['send'] == 'SEND'){

    $to      = 'queries@mydomain.com';
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['sender_nam‌​e​']." <".$_POST['sender_em‌​ail‌​'].">\r\n"; $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['sender_ema‌​il‌​']."\r\n"; 
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    //check if the mail was sent
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo json_encode(['result' => true]);
    }else {
        echo json_encode(['result' => false]);
     }
   }
?>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//send button click
$('#sendMail').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('sendmail.php', $('#myForm').serialize(), function (data) {
        //show the results if the mail was sent or not
        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (res.result === true) {
           $('#feedback').html('your mail was sent');
        }else {
           $('#feedback').html('your mail was not sent');
        }
    });
});
});
```